# Issue with a `String` and `thiserror`: `as_dyn_error` exists for reference `&String`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied` in Rust

Tags: rust, thiserror

This is my first attempt to using `thiserror` in Rust. One of the error types I want to provide is a general string which has a message but no other fields. I've attempted to copy this from the `thiserror` docs, with the only exception being the use of `#[from]`, so that I can simply return `Err(String::from("some string"))`. The code looks like this:

```
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    #[error("{0}")]
    Other(#[from] String)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=da04390bce5167455330fa2d8492b4bf)

However, this gives:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0599]: the method `as_dyn_error` exists for reference `&String`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:5:13
    |
5   |       #[error("{0}")]
    |               ^^^^^ method cannot be called on `&String` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `String: std::error::Error`
            which is required by `String: AsDynError`
            `&String: std::error::Error`
            which is required by `&String: AsDynError`
            `str: Sized`
            which is required by `str: AsDynError`
            `str: std::error::Error`
            which is required by `str: AsDynError`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

What is the issue here, any how can I resolve it, while keeping the `From` impl?

Comment: I think `#[from]` is used to define an error in term of another type that implements `std::error::Error`, but `String` does not. Maybe just `Other(String)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[from]` tag is used when your error wraps another error. In this case you do not need it. But you need to actually wrap whatever `String` with the proper `Other` constructor:

```rust
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    #[error("{0}")]
    Other(String)
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    Err(Error::Other("Hey oh let's go!".to_string()))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5d9f585ac77d3a4b295bc3ff2bc16189)